# Modify the value of an argument

Tags: java, multithreading, arguments

I'm working on multithread project. I'm trying to start a thread where I call some method from some class. This method can take a long time (some "while" loops where i haven't the control), so I would force the exit from that loops to end the thread. But I would do it using a method of the thread class (not the java.lang.Thread, but his son).

I know how to do it in C/C++ (passing an argument to the SomeClass.SomeMethod by reference) but in Java I can't (I think).

```
public class A extends Thread {

    boolean isThreadClosing = false;

    @Override
    void run ( ) {
        // if it was C/C++ i can pass the arguments by reference
        SomeClass.SomeMethod ( isThreadClosing );
    }

    void stopThread ( ) {
        isThreadClosing = true;
    }
}

public class SomeClass {

    void SomeMethod ( boolean isThreadClosing ) {
        while ( !isThreadClosing ) {
            // do...
        }
    }
}
```

So the question is how i can actualize the value of the argument of the method SomeClass.SomeMethod(...), from the thread's class?

Here there is a solution but I don't like because i had to pass the thread's class to the methood.

```
public class A extends Thread {

    boolean isThreadClosing = false;

    @Override
    void run ( ) {
        // if it was C/C++ i can pass the arguments by reference
        SomeClass.SomeMethod ( this );
    }

    void stopThread ( ) {
        isThreadClosing = true;
    }

    boolean isClosing ( ) {
        return isThreadClosing;
    }
}

public class SomeClass {

    void SomeMethod ( A thread ) {
        while ( !thread.isClosing ( ) ) {
            // do...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check std flag `interrupted` instead `isClosing`

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, what you're trying to acheive won't work as the "loops" you're in won't stop because the value of `isThreadClosing` is changed, there's nothing checking `isThreadClosing` once the work in the "loops" is started. That would be where you got your comment `// do ..`. Pass that point, the work done won't stop cause `isThreadClosing` changes, it will once it's done with the whole code in the `while`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with a simple AtomicBoolean as a condtion of the while statement.

Given a thread class:

```
public class ThreadA extends Thread {

    private AtomicBoolean stop = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public void run(){
        someClass.someMethod(stop);            
    }

    public void stopProcessing(){
        stop.set(true);
    }

}


public class SomeClass {

    public void someMethod(AtomicBoolean stop){
        while(!stop.get()){
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

This would mean interacting with the Thread in the following way:

```
ThreadA thread = new ThreadA();
thread.start();
... 
thread.stopProcessing();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you keep `A` as a private member of `SomeClass`, and then set it when you instantiate an instance of `SomeClass`? That way you don't have to pass it into `SomeMethod`.

```
public class SomeClass {

    private A thread;

    public SomeClass(A thread) {
        this.thread = thread;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        while(!thread.isInterrupted()) { //why not use this instead of
                                         //maintaining your own flag?
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind though this design is kind of fragile because managing the lifecycle of the thread is now split between the calling code and `SomeClass`. If `A` is only going to be used by `SomeClass`, perhaps it is best to instantiate it *inside* `SomeClass` and not expose it to the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Observable pattern : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html

A can implement Observable while Someclass will implement Observer, and synchronize its own boolean state on the boolean received. You'll still need A.addObserver(SomeClass), but that's a pretty low coupling.

It may be a bit over designed (?), but it will be easy to extend at least. And it gives you much more flexibility than the while(boolean) way to go in the ways you can interrupt your computation.